# How can I get jquery.jeditable to work inside an Html.beginform() block?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-plugins

how can I get jquery.jeditable to work inside an  Html.beginform() block?

I’m trying to use jquery.jeditable plugin to edit labels on a form.  When I use this block on code -

```
<div>
    <input type="hidden" id="RubricID" value="3" />
    <div class="field">
        <div class="display-label" id="lblName">Label 1</div>
        <div class="display-field text" id="Name">Lable 1</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Inside an Html.beginform() I get an exception

```
Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to get value of the property 'settings': object is null or undefined.
```

And inside the jquery.validate.min.js file `e="on"+e.type.replace(/^validate/,"")` is highlighted. However if I put the same block of code outside the Html.beginform() it works fine.

Any ideas how I can solve this problem?

Comment: You could start by showing some javascript

Comment: Here's the script: <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $(".display-label").editable("/Course/Edit");

        });
    </script>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happenes because jeditable creates its own form which conflicts with the @Html.beginform(). Creting a view for the jeditable without a beginform works fine.